# React Redux update (re-render) a component after a period of inactivity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux, mern

How would you go about re-rendering a component (or multiple components) in a React Redux (Express / Mongo backend) app?

I built an app where multiple (authenticated) users collaborate on a Todo list like dashboard in real-time (with chat-like Notes in place of Todo's), but wanted to force a re render after a period of inactivity (possibly with a setInterval in componentDidMount?) so if one user deletes a task, it will eventually refresh on all other users dashboards after a period of time. I was thinking about combining forceUpdate with setInterval but keep reading everywhere that it should be avoided.

I am aware the real-time updates must be done with websockets, but I was wondering if a a simpler short-term solution could be used for this particular situation without resorting to websockets, since my app doesn't really need instantaneous updates.

Here is the main component (list of Notes):

```
class NoteList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getNotes();
  }
}
```

Comment: "but keep reading everywhere that it should be avoided", where and why?
The correct flow is that the UI triggers the update. The only bad thing and probably why people advice against it is because you need to handle the lifecycle and cleanup of the listeners. So on unmount you need to cancel the setTimeout. Sockets is actually quite similar, IMHO the socket listener should also be in the top component... and canceled once unmounted. That keeps the unidirectional data flow clean. Just make sure you mop up

Comment: thank you @PerSvensson. I actually only meant the forceUpdate method, several posts on SO suggest to avoid it, not the setInterval by itself. Ya I will make sure to mop up even if I take the sockets route eventually. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that the coolest way is use websocket to listen to change event. But for short-term, polling is not a bad idea. Just remember to clear the interval when your component is unmounted.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getNotes();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.props.getNotes(), 60000);
 }

 componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
 }
```

Comment: thank you, this actually worked perfect except the "this" must be removed from the setInterval method. If you can just edit that, I can select it as the correct answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I fixed it.